# IDEa puts inline comments onto new line in Groovy files whereas in Java not. Can this be changed?

Tags: intellij-idea, groovy, reformatting

I cannot find a setting that is causing this. In Groovy file, a line comment after a statement is thrown to a new line once I reformat. In Java file it sticks on the original line. I want it to stick also on groovy files. Is this not configurable?

[image]

Comment: Set Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Groovy | Wrapping and Braces | Hard wrap at: to a larger value.

Comment: That doesn't solve the thing, just basically disables wrapping at that column and moves it to a later one.

Comment: Set to -1 to disable wrapping.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I do not want to disable wrapping.

Comment: Please clarify, you don't want the long lines to wrap, but you also don't want to disable wrapping? Don't you see a contradiction here?

Comment: I want to wrap everything except for putting line comments to a new line. Like shown in the gif, Java leaves comment on the line even if it surpasses the hard wrap line, groovy does not. If there was e.g. too many parameters in a method signature, both java and groovy would wrap and that is desirable. If I remove the hard wrap, too long method signatures wouldn't wrap then. Or anything else that I would normally want to wrap. No contradiction. I want to keep wrapping, except for comments.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, it's a known Groovy formatter specific limitation: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185370.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to not wrap end of line comments in Groovy at the moment, it's a limitation of IntelliJ IDEA Groovy formatter, please [follow this issue for updates](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185370).